# failed to get server control id

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, jquery-ui

I using `.ascx`

I am trying to use my jQuery to perform some action, the below code is how I call server control id.

```
$("input").mouseenter(function() {
//some function
}

<input type="text" id="family1" value="family"1/> 
<input type="text" id="family2" value="family"2 runat="server"/>
```

My problem right now is my family1 able to call jQuery function but my family doesn't.
Is it because I am using `.ascx` so I cannot pass the server control id to my jQuery?
Is that any idea to solve?

Comment: jQuery is essentially JavaScript and so is being ran from the browser. Have you checked the HTML received by the browser to make sure `family2` is the actual `id` being generated? I understand that `id`s for server controls are sometimes different from the one you specify in your markup.

Comment: You can try to do the same using the ID. This should work 

`$("#family2").mouseenter(function() {
//some function
}`

Comment: need a better explanation of problem. Code and html shhow no relationship to any server control ID

Comment: Where you are passing your server control id? post that piece of code.

Comment: when u hover on this text box u need the id of that particular text box...mi r8??

Comment: use firebug in mozilla..ndd chk the correct id by right clicking on that control..

Comment: @vignesh, this is not working by adding #

Comment: @charlietfl , my piece of code works fine without runat="server", and i need to know y

Comment: @YograjGupta $("input").mouseenter(function() { is where i pass my control to jquery

Comment: @SHAURAJSINGH due to some limitation issues i can only use IE

Comment: @Zhihao my pieces of code works fine, but after i adding runat='server' to each of the control then my code is not working properly anymore, i am still guessing that is it is my .ascx problems?

Comment: no prob press F12...it prompt u with some control...in that 1 pointer vl be thr,click that  nd after that select your control, u vl get the correct id...then tell me the id wht u seeing thr.

Comment: @SHAURAJSINGH this is the id that i get from ie ctl00_m_g_3b0d8e69_1961_4bea_886d_413493ff7f9c_ctl00_family

Comment: nd tell me the class name also..

Comment: @CheemunLow If you are using the **element** `id` in your jQuery selector, and it works *until* you add `runat='server'` then it would likely mean that the `id` of your **element** (not your **control**) is changed when the control is processed by the server. It doesn't matter to jQuery what code you have in your markup or on your server. What matters is the HTML the browser receives and what the `id` is on the client, since that is what jQuery sees. Please check the HTML on your browser. If it is different, then the solution is probably with `ClientID` as mentioned by many of answerers.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.ctl00_m_g_3b0d8e69_1961_4bea_886d_413493ff7f9c_ctl00_checkclass').hover(function (event) {
            alert('dada');
            var c = alert($(this).attr("id"));
            alert(c);
        });
    });


<input type="text" id="family1" value="family1" class="checkclass"/> 
<input type="text" id="family2" value="family2" class="checkclass" /> 
<input type="text" id="family3" value="family3" class="checkclass" />
```

Comment: ur code works fine in .html and .aspx but not .ascx , and this is what i facing right now =(

Comment: You have to attach a handler on a class name not an id, because an id is floating in asp.net because of parent containers

Comment: r u using any masterpage???if u r using then you r nt getting the correct id..above i posted how u cn get the correct id with masterpagename..chk that..

Answer (score 0):

You can get that, by using `ClientID`

Please check [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1503334.aspx/1)

Answer (score 0):

Use this `ClientIDMode="Static"`

```
 <input type="text" id="family2" ClientIDMode="Static" value="family" runat="server"/>
```

### Edit 1

**ClientIdMode="Static"**: This is most basic, simple mode and it makes the client side ID static. 
Whatever value you put for the ClientID or ID is that which will be used for the client side ID.
 One odd condition here, if a static ClientIDMode is used in a repeating control, the developer is responsible for ensuring client side ID uniqueness.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34151/ASP-NET-4-0-Client-ID-Feature

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$("#<% family2.ClientID %>").mouseenter(function() {
    //some function
 }
```

because you can reuse your control, asp.net is adding some prefix to your ID. This resulting ID varries from page to page. You can check which is the resulting ID on your page and hardcode the ID into the jQuery Selector but using clientID is the way to go. 
You can use it on all pages with your control without worries.