# Jquery not working in content pages asp net 3.5

Tags: jquery

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#btnClick").click(function(){
    alert("Hello World");
    });
    });
</script>
<div>
    <asp:Button ID="btnClick" runat="server" Text="Click" />
</div>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>"
```

this is my code

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 $('#<%= btnClick.ClientID %>').click(function()....
```

or

use `on` delegate

```
  $(document).on('click','#<%= btnClick.ClientID %>',function()....
```

Comment: I Have loaded in Masterpage

Comment: then get the correct id of your button i.e. included with masterpage name

Comment: bipen its working for only first time second time its not working

Comment: SHAURAJ SINGH i can not understand please explain it

Comment: are updating tht html or something ?? updated my answer check it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15239625/failed-to-get-server-control-id/15239805#15239805

Comment: read my all comment in that question,u vl get the answer..i hv mentioned their how to get the correct id of yr any html contol.

Comment: SHAURAJ SINGH  I will check it

Comment: wht happen is it working or not????

Comment: k den plz accept the answer..

Answer (score 1):

it should be

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('input[id$="btnClick"]').click(function(){
    alert("Hello World");
    });
    });
```

see [NAMING CONTAINER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.namingcontainer.aspx)
you should also look at [jquery element selector whose ID or name ends with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) :-

Comment: Its Not working Pranav

Comment: i am sorry..at first i added element start with selector while it should be ends with ...i have updated the answer ...

Answer (score -2):

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
       $(document).ready(function(){
         $("#btnClick").click(function(){
            alert("Hello World");
         });
       });
    </script>
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="btnClick" runat="server" Text="Click" />
    </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </asp:Content>
```

here yout script should b like this...

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
        <script type="text/javascript" >
           $(document).ready(function(){
$("#ctl00_m_g_3b0d8e69_1961_4bea_886d_413493ff7f9c_ctl00_btnClick").click(function(){
                alert("Hello World");
             });
           });
        </script>
        <div>
            <asp:Button ID="btnClick" runat="server" Text="Click" />
        </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </asp:Content>
```

and smthing like this shoud be yr control id::
$("#ctl00_m_g_3b0d8e69_1961_4bea_886d_413493ff7f9c_ctl00_btnClick").click(function()){}

Comment: This is not a good solution , the prefix will or may change ..depending upon platforms and that time this will not work